# CSS susbmenu is displaying under jQuery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have created a css vertical menu for the left side of webpage which includes submenus as well and then I have used jQuery UI tabs which I included on the right side of webpage (in asp.net), but the problem here is that my submenus are displaying under (at back side of) jQuery tabs as shown in below image:

[image]

I am very bad in CSS and designing, how can I solve this?

Comment: use `z-index`....OR create fiddle..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use z-index example below.....

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>    
</div>
```

Its CSS

```
.menu{position:relative; z-index:99;}
.content{position:relative; z-index:0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use like this...
Use z-index example below.....

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>    
</div>
```